# Camel v3.14 does not register global deserializer to unmarshall json

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

Using Apache camel v3.14.x with idk 1.8 and I am not using **springboot** but war deploys to EAP. I have all the desired camel and spring dependencies including `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310`

I have this configuration working fine with camel v2.x but when I upgrade camel to v3.14.x I start to get following error.
..

```
Error During Camel route Processing - Java 8 date/time type 'java.time.LocalDate' not supported by default add module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

I can see "jsr310" registered in modules of Objectmapper registered modules set if I debug.

if I `@autowire objectMapper` in camel route and manually `objectmapper.readValue(input, Model.class)` it seems to work fine.

Seems like camel is not picking up object mapper already created but creating its own,
any help is apperciated.

```
@Configuration
public class CamelConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration{
 
  @override
  public void setupCamelContext(CamelContext context){
  context.setAllowOriginalMessage(false);
  context.setLogMask(true);
  context.setAutoStartup(false);
    
  }
 
  @Bean
  public CamelRoutesStarter routesStarter(CamelContext context){
   return new CamelRoutesStarter(context)
  }

}

@Configuration
public class serviceConfig {
@primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
  Jackson2Obj ectMapperBuilder.json().serializationIncludsion(non_empty)
  .featureToDisable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS).deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, new CustomDateDeserialier())
 }
}

@override
public class CustomDateDeserialier extends StdScalarDeserilaizer<LocalDate>{

  public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeseralizationContext context){
    ..
  }
}

// my camel route
@Component
public MyRoute{

from("my http request")
.unmarshal().json(Jackson, Model.class)
.to("bla bla");

}

// my model
public class Model {

public LocalDate date;

}
```

**instead if I try following it works.**

```
@Component
    public MyModifiedRoute{
    
    @Autowire
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private JacksonDataFormat dataFmt;

    @PostConstruct()
    public void post(){
      dataFmt = new JacksonDataFormat(mapper, Model.class)
     }

    from("my http request")
    .unmarshal(dataFmt) //.json(Jackson, Model.class)
    .to("bla bla");
    
    }
}
```